# Connection Failed. SQL State 28000 Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

The front end MS Access database I maintain was recently switched to a new server by our server department. Previously, if a user opened the DB they did not have to log on or anything. However now we receive
[this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poahu.png)

Once clicking OK [this pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub3En.png) defaulting to the user's windows login ID with "use trusted connection" checked by default. Although I've gone through the DSN settings time and time again and changed it to the appropriate Login ID/Password for the server. It still keeps defaulting back to the same windows login info. If I uncheck the box and type in the correct login information it allows me to the table, form etc.

Without getting the server team involved again, is there any possible way I can fix this from my end? We have multiple users at multiple sites using the database which is why we put it online (SQL) to begin with. I want to roll out an update soon and would love to have this issue resolved.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the mark at *Trusted Connection* (= Windows authentication) and provide the user credentials for *SQL Server*. If not known, get them from the DBA.

Comment: Yeah that works to get in, but I want to save the settings with the correct user credentials

Comment: The old information is probably saved in your code building the _connection_ string, so you would have to modify this.

Comment: That would be them then, I had the tables locally and several years ago they switched them to SQL due to the database running slow. I found their login table with the user ID I was provided as well as their admin ID. The table isn't able to be modified (add records etc.) so it must be set to read only.